# CLT and almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $S_n$ = $X_1+\dots+X_n$ be a sum of i.i.d. mean zero random variables with a finite, positive variance. How can I show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $S_n/\sqrt n$ = $\infty$ a.s.? Also there is no limit $S_n/\sqrt n \rightarrow Y$ , even if we allow $Y$ to take values ±$\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Fatou's lemma and the CLT for any $K>0$ we have

$$
\mathsf{P}(S_n/\sqrt{n}>K \text{ i.o.}) \ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathsf{P}(S_n/\sqrt{n}>K)= 1-\Phi(K)>0.
$$

Thus, $\mathsf{P}(\limsup S_n/\sqrt{n}\ge K)>0$. Since $A_K=\{\limsup S_n/\sqrt{n}\ge K\}$ is an exchangeable event, by the [Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law) $\mathsf{P}(A_K)=1$.

$\therefore \limsup S_n/\sqrt{n}=\infty$ a.s. Similarly, $\liminf S_n/\sqrt{n}=-\infty$ so that $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ does not converge a.s.